# prevent jQuery from creating duplicate clones via .clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So I have an element with a few children elements and when I attempt to use jQuery.clone() on the parent it clones the parent (with all of it's children) and then clones the kiddos once again. To clarify with an example:

Javascript:

```
$(parent).clone(false).appendTo(container);
```

Original HTML

```
<parent>
    <element1>
    <element2>
</parent>

<container></container>
```

Modified HTML:

```
<parent>
    <element1>
    <element2>
</parent>

<container>
    <parent>
        <element1>
        <element1>
    </parent>
    <element1>
    <element2>
</container>
```

Now, I would need a way to prevent the function from cloning the elements, without using IDs or classes, since I can't predict the content of the parent.

EDIT: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lunability/TWdD2/)!

Thank you,

Luna

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen this behavior. Can you maybe include the code you're trying to clone? (Or maybe provide a jsFiddle.net demonstrating it?)

Comment: Fiddle coming up: http://jsfiddle.net/lunability/TWdD2/

Comment: Oh, about that span.lol: I fixed the leaking out, so you can ignore that. ^^

Comment: Just the clone function does not reproduce your error, there is something else wrong with you code. Check out this simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usRVZ/) example.

Comment: @withadot: It's because you're using `.each()` with two classes (selectors) specified [`.boxBlur, .lol` specifically]. EITHER find `.boxBlur` OR find `.lol`. Currently, you're duplicating `.boxBlur` (which also duplicated child `.lol`), then moves on to `.lol` (As per the selector) and duplicates yet again.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now I have another problem, but I think I might have some clue as to how to fix this one. :D Thanks (both of you). <333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call clone from within an `.each()` it's going to go through each selector (in your case you're supplying the class to both the parent and it's child) and duplicate/append each found item. Put simply:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>

$('.parent, .child').each(function(i,e){
  $(this).clone().appendTo('.container');
});
```

Will:

1. Find `.parent` (which, by hierarchy) will also find both `.child`ren, duplicate them, and append them.
2. Will find each child and also append them (leaving you with the impression clone is double-duplicating).

Instead, depending on your set-up, just clone the parent, make the modifications, and append *that* result.

If you're looking to just clone the descendant of .parent, try using a different selector (maybe `.parent > .child` to show a direct child relationship). e.g. `$('.parent > .child').clone();`

*(I've posted this as an answer as I felt a comment wasn't sufficient for anyone else who may find this question as a resource)*

Comment: Yay! I'm sure everyone will be as grateful as I am!

Comment: @withadot: Good luck! ;-) If you don't end up working out the other issue, feel free to update the question or flag me down with a `@brad` in this post with a link and I'll do my best to help.